# Behat reusable actions add header

Tags: php, symfony, behat

I'm using Behat in a Symfony2 app.

I have made a reusable action to add a HTTP header on some scenarios

```
/**
* @Given I am authenticated as admin
*/
public function iAmAuthenticatedAsAdmin()
{
    $value = 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx';

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->set('Authorization', $value);
    $response->send();

    return $response;
 }
```

This action is call when I add the `I am authenticated as admin` step in my scenario but it doesn't add my header. Like this

```
Scenario: I find all my DNS zones
  Given I am authenticated as admin
  And I send a GET request to "/api/dns"
  Then the response code should be 200
```

How can I add a HTTP header before my request step in my scenario, using a reusable action ?
Is it possible ?

Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find the way to do this.

If you are using [WebApiExtension](https://github.com/Behat/WebApiExtension)

Just import the WebApiContext in your context class like this

```
/**
 * @param BeforeScenarioScope $scope
 *
 * @BeforeScenario
 */
public function gatherContexts(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
{
    $environment = $scope->getEnvironment();

    $this->webApiContext = $environment->getContext('Behat\WebApiExtension\Context\WebApiContext');
}
```

And you just have now to use the `iSetHeaderWithValue` :

```
/**
 * @Given I am authenticated as admin
 */
public function iAmAuthenticatedAsAdmin()
{
    $name = 'Authorization';
    $value = 'Bearer xxxxxxxx';

    $this->webApiContext->iSetHeaderWithValue($name, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply store it in session (hint: session should be destroyed at every scenario; take a look to [BeforeScenario](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/3.hooks.html#hooks)) and use whenever you need it?

Because I guess it's added but, on next request, it's gone as a brand new pair of request/response are generated (if I understand your needs correctly)

Comment: I tried with `BeforeScenario` it's adding my header before each scenarios but this header is not used during the request execution. `BeforeScenario` and my custom action are doing the same thing. I think the problem is that the request don't use the header added by these actions